# Firefox doesn't start

Tags: firefox

After installing Firefox 4, it doesn't start.

Comment: How did you install Firefox 4?

Comment: Please try to start firefox from a terminal, and note the output, if any.  Add any relevant output to your question.

Comment: thks. its solved. there was nothing wrong. the folder .mozilla had  a strange user permission.

Comment: What did you do to change permissions? chown followed by chmod?

Answer (score 0):

This link below explains how to get firefox4 from packages from a ppa and install.

http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-install-firefox-4-in-ubuntu-using-ppa.html

Just reproducing here for making it easy.

Install firefox 4 using GUI

Go to Applications > Ubuntu Software Center from the top panel go to Edit > Software Sources and click the ‘Other Software’ tab.Press ‘Add’ button and then paste the following line

ppa:mozillateam/firefox-stable

After adding the PPA you will be prompted to update your sources.

Once the update is done you can head to System > Administration > Update Manager to perform an upgrade.

Install firefox 4 using terminal

Go to Applications > Terminal in the terminal just enter the following commands

```
 sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mozillateam/firefox-stable

    sudo apt-get update

`sudo apt-get upgrade` (or `sudo apt-get install firefox` will upgrade current version)
```

Comment: tks. I made a new installation but it still the same. when I click to open the browser it looks like it's running than it disappear. Maybe I'm doing something wrong ;)

Comment: Did you try complete re-install? Choose firefox from Ubuntu Software Center and remove. Once completely removed, install again.   Or from command line, 'sudo apt-get purge firefox' to completely remove it and 'sudo apt-get install firefox'

Comment: well I follow the instruction to remove firefox and I even re-start the system but after re-install it still the same. Firefox starting and then stops and gone.

Comment: solved. I change the folder permission and it works. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: seems the problem is with the folder permissions. I tried to run the profile manager and I got this IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/kauberdi/.mozilla/firefox.last-version' i check the folder .mozilla and the folder owner is set to 1016 - user #1016 – Amilcar Aristides Monteiro

Comment: This answer is now incorrect as this PPA is being retired.